# iOS7 Keep UINavigationBar and animate only the view on segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

There is one thing i thinking about for days now. I want to keep the same navigation bar on every viewcontroller in my app (like in the amazon app) and show the push animation (push segue) only on the view itself without touching the nav bar.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: can you please explain elaborately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of the views are inside the same UINavigationController, then the nav bar will not be changed at all when you use the push segue. If you don't want any nav bar title animations, etc just set the same title/buttons on the next view, and it will look like nothing changed. When the new view controller is pushed, the nav bar will remain the same, and only what's under it will change.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice that i dont have a custom UINavigationController... My bad.